# RestKit getObjectsAtURL?

Tags: rest, restkit

I'm using RestKit to connect to the RESTful API provided by our server. Our API paginates list results, and includes a next-page url in its response. The problem is, I don't find a way to use that URL to get the next page. Instead, I only find *getObjectsAtPath*, which accepts a relative URL path. **Does RestKit have something like *getObjectsAtURL*?**

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `NSURLRequest` using the URL and then use `objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` (or the managed object equivalent method if required) to create and execute an operation to load that request.